# How to check whether the email account is valid?

Tags: java

I have already written code to check the email account it is working for gmail & yahoo mail
but it is not working for hotmail & AOL. Below is the code I have used. If any idea please help.

I am getting following exception when I pass hotmail account:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
 nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

Code:

```
public boolean checkEmailAccountInfo(final String userMailID,
        final String password, String outgoingMailServer, String portNo) {

    try {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        // Boolean b = new Boolean(true);
        p.put("mail.smtps.auth", true);
        p.put("mail.smtp.user", userMailID);
        p.put("mail.smtp.host", outgoingMailServer);
        p.put("mail.smtp.port", portNo);
        p.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
        p.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        p.put("mail.smtp.8BITMIME", "true");
        p.put("mail.smtp.PIPELINING", "true");
        p.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", 465);
        p.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");

        p.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        p.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        // create some properties and get the default Session

        javax.mail.Session session = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(p,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(userMailID,
                                password);
                    }
                });
        session.setDebug(false);

        Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
        t.connect();
        boolean isConnected = t.isConnected();
        if (isConnected) {
            t.close();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: just send an email and wait till you get response from them :P

Comment: Do you mean that you are actually trying to connect to Hotmail / AOL directly?  Maybe the problem is that Hotmail / AOL don't want you checking email addresses like this ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try for this :

```
p.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", portNo);
```

This will work .I have tested it with other mail ids.

Comment: You can not check is email address valid or not.Mail api checks for server ip using host name not email address.

Comment: Can you please give me an example.

Comment: Here is list of all smtp out going and incoming port and host: check this link http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/tips/mail-settings.html